# Xcode can’t be installed on “MACINTOSH HD” because macOS version 13 or later is required

Tags: flutter, xcode, macos-monterey

I am currently running macOS Monterey Version 12.6.6 and I cannot install Xcode for Flutter, the prompt is "Xcode can’t be installed, macOS version 13 or later is required."  Can anyone provide assistance because I cannot update my Mac to the required version.

I tried to install older version of Flutter but I am not sure where I can get it accompanied Xcode version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download an older version of xcode from

https://xcodereleases.com/

Or

For xcode 14.0.1 compatible with your Mac
https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_14.0.1/Xcode_14.0.1.xip